# Cannot connect to google cloud VM instance

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am trying to connect google cloud instance (I am already authenticated through my google account) but from Mac OS terminal, but keep getting an error:
[TerminalWindow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQEkN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is instruction for you, check it https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/google-cloud-compute-engin-ssh-into-an-instance-from-linux-unix-appleosx/